# Order object not display under checkout_submit_all_after observer

Tags: magento2, php, onestepcheckout

Created event:

```
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
    <observer name="iversa_runningbox_shipment_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="Iversa\RunningboxShipment\Observer\CheckoutAllSubmitAfterObserver"/>
</event>
```

And observer code:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
  $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
  file_put_contents('checkouttest.txt', print_r($order_id,true), FILE_APPEND);//This value is showing in log file
  file_put_contents('checkouttest.txt', print_r($order,true), FILE_APPEND);//This value is NOT showing in log file
  file_put_contents('checkouttest.txt', print_r($order->getAllItems(),true), FILE_APPEND);//This value is NOT showing in log file
}
```

Order object and get all product items is not showing result

Answer (score 0):

You need to observer this event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

events.xml code as below

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="iversa_runningbox_shipment_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="Iversa\RunningboxShipment\Observer\CheckoutAllSubmitAfterObserver"/>
</event>
```

Add below code to observer

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class [ClassName] implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_order;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
         $this->_order = $order;    
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $orderids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

        foreach($orderids as $orderid){
            $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);
        }
    }

}
```